# Google Analytics: Flag internal session and filter them in

Tags: google-analytics

Normally, we filter out all the internal traffics in Google analytics. But sometimes I might need this traffic for some particular analysis. Can I flag these Internal traffics and includes them in some of my reports?

Comment: Off topic as this isn't related to coding, but to comment, you should create a view specifically for internal traffic where you can create the reports you're interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few tricks to identify internal and external traffic
http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/04/27/internal-traffic-google-analytics/

One more thing that you can do is create a new view with a filter that only includes data for your internal traffic

Hope this helps,